# Turn Ruby data structure of primitives into literal

Tags: ruby

I have a data structure consisting of nested built-in Ruby types, such as hashes, arrays, keywords, numbers and strings. I would like to transform that to a literal form, such that evaluating that form yields the given data structure.

For instance:

```
[ { :some => [ 'thing' ] }, 42 ] -> "[ { :some => [ 'thing' ] }, 42 ]"
```

This could be obtained by recursively visiting the structure and handling all the desired built-in types, but I am wondering if there is some suitable built-in/library solution I could use instead.

Clarification: The output is going to be used in the context of code generating Ruby code so alternatives such as JSON is not what I'm after.

Comment: `inspect` would probably suffice but that is for producing ["a human-readable representation of *obj*"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) so the output format isn't guaranteed to be what you want.

Comment: Your best choice is to use JSON. It represents Ruby arrays and hashes in a JavaScript array/hash format, which is very similar. Ruby's JSON parser makes it all very easy to generate and parse the serialized versions of the data.

Comment: I am specifically looking for something that generates literals in valid Ruby syntax, though, as the context is code generation (question updated to clarify that).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by literal? If your not talking about marshalling the data then you'll need to provide some context as your clarification really isn't much to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Object#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is probably what you're looking for. It will produce ruby representations for all the types you listed. Though that might start to fall apart for more complex types like dates, etc.

```
1.9.3 (main):0 > puts [ { :class => [ 'thing' ] }, 42 ].inspect
[{:class=>["thing"]}, 42]
```

Comment: Inspect is sufficient for my use case, even if this is not a general solution. The caveat of course being that the representation yielded by inspect is intended for 'human' and not machine interpretation. In my use case this is less of a concern since only a handful of primitive types (+ hashes/arrays) need to be supported and these work as expected with inspect. Conceivably the output for these types COULD change with future Ruby versions (since inspect provides no formal guarantees) but I can live with a test failing when that happens, if ever.

Comment: I think you're pretty safe in expecting inspect to always return valid ruby for core classes. It seems to fall back to string when there is no parseable representation. e.g. Class.new.inspect. Inspect can (and should) be overridden though so no guarantee on other objects.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options, JSON and YAML are probably the two most popular in Ruby.

```
# using JSON
serialized = JSON.dump([ { :some => [ 'thing' ] }, 42 ])
deserialized = JSON.load(serialized)

# using YAML
serialized = YAML.dump([ { :some => [ 'thing' ] }, 42 ])
deserialized = YAML.load(serialized)
```

Comment: JSON is a better choice than YAML if a "literal" form is desired. JSON serialized data looks a lot more like Ruby than YAML's representation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was specifically looking for something that generates literals in valid Ruby syntax, though, as the context is code generation (question updated to clarify that).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Marshal. It's ruby-core library.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html

From readme:

The marshaling library converts collections of Ruby objects into a byte stream, allowing them to be stored outside the currently active script. This data may subsequently be read and the original objects reconstituted.

Comment: +1 marshal dump is much faster than the other alternatives in my experience.

Comment: Yup. It's written in C (for MRI) and distributed with ruby.

Comment: I use jruby and it is still faster than the alternatives :-)

Comment: If you're going to be evaluating data from potentially untrusted sources, marshal can be a security risk.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was specifically looking for something that generates literals in valid Ruby syntax, though, as the context is code generation (question updated to clarify that).